# Ldap script works only with one email

Tags: python, powershell

Currently have this code but its not looping or working correctly.

```
$path = "D:\users.csv"
$csv = Import-Csv $path 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

foreach($line in $csv){
    $User = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$($line.Email)))"
    If ($User -eq $Null) {
        "User does not exist in AD   " + $line.Email 
    } Else {
        "User found in AD  - " + $line.Email
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain more about _not looping_ and _not working correctly_.. Do you get error messages?. Does testing with `If (!$User)` instead of `If ($User -eq $Null)` give you what you want?

Comment: Please add an example of your csv formatting as well with your headers

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:python]?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know how it goes:
 first in your csv file add header Name and underneath it all the users to be added.
Name
John
Nancy
etc...
then for powershell

```
$file = "D:\users.csv"
$inputs = Import-Csv -path $file |select -expandproperty Name
foreach($input in $inputs){
your rest of code here...`enter code here`
}
```